# torchにおけるサイズ[N,1]と[1,N]の掛け合わせ方

Tags: python, python3, pytorch

torch形式のベクトルA(サイズ[N,1])とB=A'(サイズ[1,N])を掛け合わせてサイズ[N,N]の行列を算出したいと考えています。
しかし`torch.matmul`や`torch.mm`ではエラーが出てきてしまうか、A'A(サイズ[1,1])が出てきてしまいます。

`A = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_N]'`とすれば算出したい行列Cの(i,j)成分は

```
for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
       C(i,j) = a_i * a_j
```

となりますが、できれば高速にこの計算を行いたいです。何か良い方法はないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

torch 1.6.0で`matmul`も`mm`も動作しているように思います。

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn(3, 1)
>>> b = torch.randn(1, 3)
>>> a.size()
torch.Size([3, 1])
>>> b.size()
torch.Size([1, 3])
>>> torch.matmul(a, b)
tensor([[ 0.0096,  0.3664,  0.2490],
        [-0.0145, -0.5553, -0.3773],
        [ 0.0282,  1.0820,  0.7353]])
>>> torch.mm(a, b)
tensor([[ 0.0096,  0.3664,  0.2490],
        [-0.0145, -0.5553, -0.3773],
        [ 0.0282,  1.0820,  0.7353]])
>>> torch.matmul(b, a)
tensor([[0.1896]])
```

Comment: Ver. 1.7.0でも行けました。ありがとうございます。